# Alexa default service don't work after coming out of my custom alexa skill, it returns "Sorry I am having trouble, Please try after a little while"

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have my own skill "Control Room", Before invoking my skill I can ask general questions from alexa like jokes, weather but once I invoke my skill and then come out of it with AMAZON.stopIntent then after that the default voice service does not work. Every time I ask a question, alexa returns "Sorry I am having trouble, Please try after a little while"

What can be wrong, how my skill can affect this

Comment: Provide example code, and what you have already done to try and fix the problem.

Comment: I have used the AlexaPi for raspberrypi, and the skill I have created is a simple app to invoke the intents and send a speech response. I don't know where is the problem, it's not only with my skill, I enabled an custom skill from amazon skill store and same thing happened.

Comment: Then the problem is not with your skill but with your AVS device.

Comment: How AVS device can be the problem, I have verified that when the issue happened I am properly capturing the audio sending it in the correct format and receiving the response with HTTP 200 but the audio payload contains "Sorry I am having trouble Please try in a little while".

Comment: Interesting thing is that this issue goes away after a little while and works fine. But If I again enter the skill and exit the session issue happens again.   Looks like there is some kind of wait period after exiting the custom skill. One more point is that when AVS is sending this trouble response for general questions, my skill still works, AVS let me enter the skill and skill completely works fine. Only thing is that after exiting the skill I have to wait for some time to ask normal/general questions from Alexa

Comment: AVS response when issue occurs

 ` "POST /v1/avs/speechrecognizer/recognize HTTP/1.1" 200 None --3ff3bc3f-7134-4aca-997e-e0c58c76ae71 Content-Type: application/json {"messageHeader":{},"messageBody":{"directives":[{"namespace":"SpeechSynthesizer","name":"speak","payload":{"contentIdentifier":"amzn1.as-ct.v1.#ACRI#ErrorNotifier_02c66e2c-8a33-4e3d-8a1b-e2a378b7f98b","audioContent":"cid:ErrorNotifier_02c66e2c-8a33-4e3d-8a1b-e2a378b7f98b_608085105"}}]}} --3ff3bc3f-7134-4aca-997e-e0c58c76ae71 Content-ID: <ErrorNotifier_02c66e2c-8a33-4e3d-8a1b-e2a378b7f98b_608085105> Content-Type: audio/mpeg `